# If repeat likes are allowed, how do you add 1 to a like count in instances where the new like entry replaces the old one and doesn't get counted?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

So there is a child, that acts like this in db:

```
User A
 peopleWhoLike2: ///all those who liked user A
  User B: 1603993939.  //// UserB liked A: Timestamp of the like. Repeats get replaced
 TodayLikeCount: 1
```

Now in certain instances repeat likes are allowed (so a new one replaces the old one in peopleWhoLike2 child). That would mess with the "TodayLikeCount". Below is how it works for instances where user B has not liked User A yet. How can you add one more if User B had already liked user A (to account for the DB entry replacement)?

Additional note: In the below code, the first segment updates the total likes. The second segment addresses the TodayLikeCount. The 2nd is the concern of the question. In a nutshell, if an entry of user B liking user A already exists and user B likes user A, the DB entry is simply replaced and then the count doesn't become one more. It should add 1 to TodayLikeCount in that instance.

As to what segment 1 does (it does not have a problem but segment 2 is inside it, so I added it). Segment 2 updates the Total likes and it does so by counting peopeWhoLike child, where replacement doesn't occur- hence no problem

```
//Segment 1
let keyToPost = ref.child("likes").childByAutoId().key
ref.child("people").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  {(snapshot) in
   if let people = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
   let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
      ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in

    if error == nil {
       ref.child("people").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
         if let properties = snap.value as?[String: AnyObject]{
            if let likes = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let count = likes.count
            let update = ["likes" : count]
            ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)                                           
}                      
}                
})
    
///Segment 2
**let thisUserRef1 = ref.child("people").child(self.postID)
let myPeopleRef1 = thisUserRef1.child("peopleWhoLike2")
myPeopleRef1.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in

let peopleArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
let filteredResults = peopleArray.filter { person in
    let personUid = person.value as! Int
    let coordSnap12 = personUid
    print("kjk", coordSnap12 )
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(coordSnap12)/1000.0)
    //let secondsInDay = 86400
    
    return Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date)
    
}

print(filteredResults, "ppp")
let countb = filteredResults.compactMap({$0}).count
print(countb, "kji")
let updateLikes1 = ["TodayLikeCount" : countb]
ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes1)
})
}
})   
}   
})**
```

Comment: Please format your code to remove extra indentation and extra empty lines

Comment: Getting to the point, *That would mess with the "TodayLikeCount"* - is the issue. If the user already has an existing node, just update it with the new timestamp, don't change TodayLikeCount. If the user doesn't have an existing node, add it, and update the TodayLikeCount. The cool thing here is you can observe .childAdded events to update the count - .childAdded will only fire if a child is added.

Comment: @Jay thanks. I fixed it this morning, did just that

Comment: Great! Does that mean it corrected the issue?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you.